# Error in Connecting Data Base using Data Connections

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008

I am having MS-VS 2010 and Sql Server 2008 R2,

In Visual Studio From Data Connections if I tried to connect the data base the test connection is getting succeeded and the db is added. But if I click add new diagram it is throwing the message as,

"This db does not have a valid dbo user or you do not have permissions to impersonate the dbo user, so db diagramming is NA. Do you want to make yourself the dbo of this database in order to use db diagramming"

the above message is displayed in message box if i click yes,

"The server does'nt have one or more of the db objects required to use db diagramming. Do you wish to create them?"

the above message is displayed in message box if i click yes, throwing error as

"could not obtain information about Window NT group/user 'SYSTEM-PC\SYSTEM', error code 0x534"

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use Database Diagrams in SQL Server in first time, SQL Server create `sys.diagrams` table and multi sys.functions to support diagrams. you don't have any access to create this object in sql server. but if Admin user active diagrams on your database, you can use diagrams without any special access on VS.

if Admin user select Database Diagrams item on your database on SSMS Object explorer. SSMS show following message and admin user can accept that.

```
This database does not have one or more of the support objects required to use database diagraming. 
Do you Wish to create them
```